# What is an appropriate amount of data to take in a moving average?

Tags: dataset, moving-average, automatic-algorithms

For instance, lets say I have 10,000 data points to work with for a single plot of data. I want to smooth this data using a moving average and I want this to be automated (I have already written the code). What is an appropriate amount of data points to use in calculating an average for an interval of points?

Is it a percentage? A number? And if you can, I would love to hear an explanation or be pointed toward a source that I could read myself.

I have it currently set at intervals of 1%, or about 100 data points per average. My error is not too large, but I also want to keep in mind calculation time if I need to run 1000's of datasets (which would mean tens of millions of data points).

Comment: Moving averages are most typically applied wrt time series information but you haven't indicated whether or not your data has a temporal reference. That you've set it up in terms of percentiles is fine but note that a percentile is a chunk, not a moving average. Presumably your percentiles are based on a rank ordering of the information from 1 to 100. The central tendencies (mean, median) of these quantiles are easily visualized. How and why would a "moving average" of these quantities provide any further insight?

Comment: The real issue here concerns how and why to smooth data, because the computational problem is nonexistent: using the FFT you can compute a moving average of any width for very large datasets in very little time.

Comment: Not that I have an answer, but it seems like whatever the right answer is, it would depend on what you're trying to accomplish by taking a moving average.

Comment: Are you tied to the idea of a moving average?  If smoothing your data is what you want, there exist some more advanced methods with some rules of thumb for choosing hyperparameters.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a weighted moving average? I've used it in several applications where I needed a smoothed average.

In a moving or rolling average, you have to remember all of the last *N* data points and add them up over and over again. With a weighted moving average, you only have to remember two values: the numerator and the denominator.

It works like this:

$A_1 = X_1$

$A_2 = \frac{A_1*F + X_2}{F + 1}$

$A_3 = \frac{A_1*F^2 + A_2*F + X_3}{ F^2 + F + 1}$

. . .

$A_i = \frac{A1*F^{i-1} + A2*F^{i-2} + ... + A_i}{ F^{i-1} + F^{i-2} + ... + 1}$

This can be simplified by realizing that each successive numerator can be calculated as:

$N[i+1]  =  N[i] * F  +  x[i]$

and each successive denominator by

$D[i+1]  =  D[i] * F  +  1$

then $A[i+1] = \frac{N[i+1]}{ D[i+1]}$

*F* is the weighting or discounting factor; $0 <= F <= 1.$

It sounds like something like *F* = 0.99 might work for you.

A search on "weighted moving average" will turn up lots of examples and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Started as a comment but grew too long; I guess it's an answer-by-way-of-general-advice now.

Such window-width choices involve a [*bias-variance tradeoff*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff) -- the wider  your window the smoother the result (lower variance), but the less responsive it will be (which is where the greater bias comes in), while narrower windows will have less bias but greater variance.

[image: plot showing trending time series and two smooths via moving average with different window widths -- the larger window has more bias but is smoother]

You can always try something like minimizing leave-one-out mean-square prediction error (if your interest is mainly on smoothing) or one-step-ahead prediction error (if you're using it to predict) to choose the particular smooth (such as the window width for a plain moving average). [As whuber says, speed shouldn't be a big problem with a suitable choice of algorithm.]

However, if you expect smooth trend in your data, raw moving averages may not be your best choice (see what happens when you smooth a noiseless quadratic trend, say, or a sine curve). If you're doing a smooth that looks only *back* in time ("filtering"), as you might do when predicting, even a linear trend will have this problem.  There are particular forms of weighted moving averages that can reduce that particular source of bias.